# How to extend the User model with a UserProfile that includes a one to many relation with another model

Tags: django, user-profile

I want to extend the User model with the following:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    business_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category) # the beginning of the problem
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(max_length=75)

#the problem is here
def create_client_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Client.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_client_profile, sender=User)
```

So when I try to sync the db, it complains about category_id cannot be null, and the source of the problem is "create_client_profile". How can I solve this?
If I remove "create_client_profile" it works but yes I will loose get_profile().

What do you think of [this](http://sam.odio.com/blog/2008/05/extending-user-model-profiles-in-django.php) as a solution? I am not sure it is Djangoish enough :)

Comment: How could the blog post at that link not be "Djangoish enough"? It's quite literally the way the Django docs recommend.

Comment: I am not sure if because it was posted in 2008, he was trying to solve something that is now became part of Django. And, at the beginning of the post he was complaining about the way Django does it, so according to him, he was offering something better. That is why I threw it here in order to check other's opinion

Comment: I see, he's actually recommending a different way of accessing the profile than `get_profile()`, but everything else is standard Django. It's still not an alternate "solution". Just an alternate way of working with the profile once the standard Django solution has been implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, you've got a signal that automatically creates a Client whenever a User is created. Your Client model has an obligatory ForeignKey to Category, but your signal doesn't set a category.

The solution should be obvious: either make your category FK `null=True`, or get your signal to get/create the relevant category.

Comment: I tried `null=True` before and it didn't work, but that was because of a mistake in the view code. But now it works. But I still don't understand the signal. How it will create a Client when a User is created while Client also has an obligatory name field.

Comment: CharFields default to the empty string if not supplied, so don't violate the null constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Does the database already contain data for `Client`? There might be entries with a `null` category.

If you change the `category` line in `Client` to:

```
category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null=True)
```

does it help?